# What libraries do we need to include to use CGPoint and arc4random()?

Tags: ios, swift, cgpoint

It's my first program in Swift.
The function returns two random locations (CGPoints) which are points on the perimeter of a circle of radius = variable (passed in by the calling program).
The two CGPoints must also be greater than degreesApart around the perimeter of the circle.
I have written the following code:

```
 func returnPerimeterPoints (radius: Int, degreesApart: Int) -> (CGPoint, CGPoint) {
    var perimeterPoint1 = CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%radius),y:Int(arc4random()%radius))
    var perimeterPoint2 = CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%radius),y:Int(arc4random()%radius))
return (perimeterPoint1, perimeterPoint2)
    }
print(returnPerimeterPoints(20, 24))
```

I have received the following errors:

```
cannot find 'CGPoint' in scope
cannot find 'arc4random' in scope
```

What libraries do i need to include and what can i do to get the CGPoints like i mentioned in the first paragraph?

Comment: Don't use `arc4random` with a modulo, opt for `Int.random(in:)` as this is not susceptible to *modulo bias*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGPoint` is defined in `CoreGraphics`, but will also be imported by default when importing a UI library like `UIKit` or `SwiftUI`.

`arc4random` in part of `Darwin` (the kernel) but, again, will be imported automatically when you import an Apple framework that depends on it, like `Foundation` or even `CoreGraphics` as well.

```swift
import CoreGraphics

// ... your code here
```